# How do I properly read and write Binary files? (C++)

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

In this program, I am reading, manipulating, and writing binary, bitmap files. I am trying to use C-style files for both reading and writing these files. I am also dynamically allocating the memory onto the heap using new() and delete in order to then write that block of memory to another file. 
I think I have a problem when I read and also write the binary files within my for loop. Somehow I overwrite by File and Info header after taking a look at my output file. I just need help understanding why this is happening. All my other code should be fine.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>

#pragma pack(push, 2)
struct BitmapFileHeader {

    uint16_t type;
    uint32_t size;
    uint16_t reserved_1;
    uint16_t reserved_2;
    uint32_t offset;

};
struct BitmapInfoHeader {

    uint32_t size;
    uint32_t width;
    uint32_t height;
    uint16_t planes;
    uint16_t bitcount;
    uint32_t compression;
    uint32_t imagesize;
    uint32_t x_pixels_per_meter;
    uint32_t y_pixels_per_meter;
    uint32_t color_used;
    uint32_t color_important;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

struct Pixel {
    uint8_t blue;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t red;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage : %s input_file output_file\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *fin;
    FILE *fout;
    BitmapFileHeader bfh;
    BitmapInfoHeader bih;

    fin = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

    if (nullptr == fin) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }

    if (sizeof(BitmapFileHeader) != fread(
        &bfh,
        1,
        sizeof(bfh),
        fin
    )) {
        printf("Unable to read bitmap file header. \n");
        return -2;
    }

    if (sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader) != fread(
        &bih,
        1,
        sizeof(bih),
        fin
    )) {
        printf("Unable to read bitmap info header. \n");
        return -3;
    }

    printf("Size of File Header = %lu\n", sizeof(BitmapFileHeader));

    int8_t first = (bfh.type >> 8) & 0xff;
    int8_t second = bfh.type & 0xff;

    if ( (first != 'M') && (second != 'B') ){
        printf("Input file is not a Bitmap file. \n");
        return -4;
    }

    printf("File type = %c%c\n", first, second);
    printf("File size = %u\n", bfh.size);
    printf("File offset = %u\n", bfh.offset);
    printf("File width = %u\n", bih.width);
    printf("Info size = %u\n", bih.size);

    uint32_t padding_bytes = 0;
    uint32_t row_bytes_final = bih.width * sizeof(Pixel);
    uint32_t row_bytes_initial = row_bytes_final;

    do{
        uint32_t rem = row_bytes_final % 4;

        if (rem != 0) {
            row_bytes_final += 1;
        }

        padding_bytes = row_bytes_final - row_bytes_initial;

    } while( (row_bytes_final % 4) != 0);


    fseek(fin, bfh.offset, SEEK_SET);

    Pixel *p = new Pixel[bih.height * bih.width];

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < (bih.height); i++) {

        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < bih.width; j++) {
            fread(&p[i], 1, sizeof(p), fin);
            i++;
            //Something I don't understand is wrong here. 
        }

        fseek(fin, padding_bytes, SEEK_CUR);

    }

    fclose(fin);


    fout = fopen(argv[2], "wb");

    if(nullptr == fout) {
        perror(argv[2]);
        return -5;
    }

    if( sizeof(BitmapFileHeader) != fwrite(
    &bfh, 
    1, 
    sizeof(bfh), 
    fout
    )) {
        printf("Unable to write bitmap file header.\n");
        return -6;
    }

    if( sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader) != fwrite(
        &bih, 
        1, 
        sizeof(bih), 
        fout
        )) {
            printf("Unable to write bitmap info header.\n");
            return -7;
        }

    fseek(fout, bfh.offset, SEEK_SET);

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < (bih.height) ; i++) {

        for (uint32_t j = 0; i < bih.width; j++) {
            fwrite(&p[i], 1, sizeof(p), fout);
            i++;
            //same problem
        }

        fseek(fout, padding_bytes, SEEK_CUR);

    }

    fclose(fout);
    delete p;


    //fseek(fin, bfh.offset, SEEK_SET);
    //Pixel p;
    //fread(&p, 1, sizeof(p), fin);
    //printf("R = %u, G = %u, B = %u\n", p.red, p.green, p.blue);
    return 0;

}
```

How am I overwriting my headers for my output file if I am moving my file pointer to the offset?

Comment: You may not be able to read and write raw structures due to structure padding. Try reading each component individually to be sure you don't misalign things.

Comment: This seems like a typo. `fwrite(&p[i], 1, sizeof(p), fout);` should be `fwrite(&p[i], 1, sizeof(p[i]), fout);` It has to be `sizeof(p[i])`, not `sizeof(p)`.

Comment: Doesn't " #Pragma pack(push, 2)" and " Pragma pack(pop) " remedy this?

Comment: @tadman: Why should padding different while read write is the *same* program?

Comment: I think that did the trick but my output-file is coming out very different from the input; something maybe wrong with how I am iterating with my for loops.

Comment: Odd. I fixed the typo for " j < bih,width" but the output still differs.

Comment: My test image is 306 Bytes initially. After reading and writing it becomes 81 bytes. The output has none of the pixel data.

Comment: @Klaus Good point, but presumably this is intended to interoperate with other programs using standard formats that aren't always compiler-alignment friendly.

Comment: Why the C style I/O when the question is tagged C++? [std::cout.write()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) works fine, as does [unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead of `new` / `delete`...

Comment: @ DevSolar I am using both c++ and c. I am just using C style for file streams instead of <fstreams>.

Comment: @PSIKLO watch out for the differences between the languages. Many of them are obvious because they result in code that doesn't compile in C++. Some of them are... not so obvious.

Comment: @user4581301 Noted! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the following problems in your code:

#### Problem 1

You are using the wrong argument to `sizeof` in

```
fread(&p[i], 1, sizeof(p), fin);
```

and

```
fwrite(&p[i], 1, sizeof(p), fout);
```

They need to be `sizeof(p[i])`, `sizeof(p[0])`, or `sizeof(Pixel)`. I prefer `sizeof(p[0])` since it works regardless of the type of `p[0]`.

#### Problem 2

You have a typo in

```
for (uint32_t j = 0; i < bih.width; j++) {
```

It needs to be

```
for (uint32_t j = 0; j < bih.width; j++) {
//                  ^^^ Fix
```

#### Problem 3

You are not using the right index to read into `p` and write from `p`.

```
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < bih.height; i++) {
   for (uint32_t j = 0; j < bih.width; j++) {

      // Using p[i] is not correct. You need to use the right index.
      // sizeof(p[0]) is just as good as sizeof(p[index]) here.

      uint32_t index = i*bih.width + j;
      fread(&p[index], 1, sizeof(p[0]), fin);
   }
   fseek(fin, padding_bytes, SEEK_CUR);
}
```

The loop for writing needs to be fixed similarly.

```
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < bih.height; i++) {
   for (uint32_t j = 0; j < bih.width; j++) {
      uint32_t index = i*bih.width + j;
      fwrite(&p[index], 1, sizeof(p[0]), fout);
   }
   fseek(fout, padding_bytes, SEEK_CUR);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! Could I make the calculation for index within the brackets like so?   fread(&p[i*bih.width +j), 1 , sizeof(p[0]), fin);

Comment: @PSIKLO, you can. IMO, calculating it in a statement of its own makes the code more readable.

Comment: @PSIKLO, just an FYI. You can make your program quite a bit modular. See https://ideone.com/RudVCX.

Comment: @R Sahu Thanks. I definitely see this being written better. I just wasn't thinking about modularity when starting this. I will definitely rewrite it and next time keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think 
`fread(&p[i], 1, sizeof(p), fin);` should be `fread(&p[i], 1, sizeof(Pixel), fin);`

Sizeof a pointer is (based on architecture) generally either 4 or 8 bytes. your pixel class is 3 bytes (with #pragma pack(push, 1)).

May be use `fread(&p[i], sizeof(Pixel), bih.width, fin);`
Be aware though, ordering and padding can vary on different architecture.

Comment: I made the change but I am getting the same results. Is it a bad idea to try to use a for loop within a for loop? Maybe I should us a 2-D array.

Comment: Loop is ok as well. Generally, i/o is slower than loops, if you can read in chunk, it will be faster. For example, x times i/o will be slower than single i/o call.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed the delay with Large files.